# webserver serves post content in chunked encoding

Tags: webserver, fastcgi, chunked

I have a question about web server (Nginx, Apache, etc)'s ability to serve posted content in chunked encoding.

Suppose we have two clients. Client 1 is posting chunked encoded content to a web server, and client2 is requesting the same content at the same time from the web server. Is the web server able to send the chunks to client2 in chunked encoding while receiving the chunks from client1?

I am thinking about client1 posting content to a fcgi backend, which also serves the content to client2. But it seems that many web server implementations buffer the chunks from client1 and only send the entire post body to the fcgi backend. This introduces unnecessary delay.

Any idea how to remove this delay?

Thanks.

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is a open discussion about possible ways to implement a functionality. No code is needed, I am looking for suggestions.

Comment: This isn't a forum and discussion questions are not a good fit here.  To be on-topic a question here must have a specific programming related problem that can have a canonical accepted answer.  See this meta post about why discussion questions are off-topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288851/1145388